# Unable to re-rip CDs in Windows Media Player

Tags: format, ripping, cd, wav

Using Windows Media Player to rip my CD collection I had noise issues with MP3 even at highest quality. I have a few dozen ripped this way. I started using WAV format and all is great. I have plenty of drive space so WAV is fine with me. WMP won't let me go back and re-rip my first few dozen CDs even with Format and Quality changed. It says "already ripped" and all ripping buttons are greyed out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is on a Microsoft Surface Pro running Windows 10

Comment: Try (1) Menu *Tools > Options > Privacy" to use "Clear History" and "Clear Caches", (2) Rename the CD in the library.

Comment: Or use any of the * many* thirds-party CD ripping tools, e.g., https://fixthephoto.com/best-free-cd-ripper.html